# adding php variable BETWEEN statment to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if($band == "something"){
     $que = "BETWEEN '1000' and '2000'";
}

if($band == "somethingelse"){
     $que = "BETWEEN '2000' and '5000'";
}

if($band == "somethingelseelse"){
     $que = "BETWEEN '5000' and '10000'";
}

if($band == "againsomethingelse"){
     $que = "BETWEEN '10000' and '30000'";
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col $que order by datetime desc LIMIT 50");
```

Can't seem to find what i am missing here... I want to make the "between" statement into a php variable so it will change the query items with a given input. there are multiple different inputs for different ranges. when I enter the between manually such as (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 order by datetime desc LIMIT 50) I have no problems. it dose not work with the variable
This is my first post here so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Comment: i am not having any luck with this. if I manually enter the between statement it works no problems. when it is entered through a variable as shown it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($band == "something"){
 $que = "BETWEEN '1000' AND '2000'";
}else{
  $que = "BETWEEN '2000' AND '5000'";
}

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col $que ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 50");
```

Comment: The `$band` variable will compare in the inputted `$variable` or string. And will insert the query. If not it will go to else statement.

Comment: the problem with the if / else is that I have more than just two sets of numbers i want to select.

Comment: Use `switch{ case "something": $b = 1000; break;  case "somethingelse": $b = 2000; break; }` for a set of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET["band"] == "something"){
 $quelow = 1000;
 $quehigh = 2000;

}

if($_GET["band"] == "somethingelse"){
 $quelow = 2000;
 $quehigh = 5000;
}

if($_GET["band"] == "somethingelseelse"){
 $quelow = 5000;
 $quehigh = 10000;
}

if($_GET["band"] == "againsomethingelse"){
 $quelow = 10000;
 $quehigh = 20000;
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col BETWEEN $quelow AND $quehigh order by datetime desc LIMIT 50");
```

I solved this one on my own with a bit of futzing i was getting the php variable improperly from my webpage. Working no problem any questions let me know!